# Daylightsavings changes send to RTC / BIOS

Tags: server, rtc

I'm using a Fujitsu D3417-B2 as headless homeserver with Ubuntu. Via Cron it is set to sleep every evening and via BIOS is wakes up every morning.

Works really well until the clocks are set back or forth due to daylightsaving regulation.

Being a headless server it's quite a pain re-adjusting the clock in the BIOS.
Normally BIOS' have a setting for this, but this particular board does not.
[image]

So I went on and searched for and software-solution. I thought maybe it would be possible to re-adjust the BIOS (RTC) clock via Ubuntu (ssh) twice per year and then I would be fine.

I found the command:
sudo hwclock --set...  and it seemed very promising. But it doesnt seem to adjust the BIOS RTC clock at all.. 
I tested it a few times but after each Reboot e.g. Shutdown+Powerup the BIOS clock was still one hour behind UTC.

So I correctly set the Time in BIOS, put the Server back in it's place and decided to consult the wisdom of the professional community here before wasting more time.

If it's not possible at all, I'm okay living with this issue and planning this maintenance twice a year in my schedule. But maybe im just knocking the wrong door.

Thanks alot for reading and supporting.

Michael